# My website doesn't scroll on mobile devices

Tags: css, mobile, mobile-safari, viewport

I can't find a way to enable scroll on my website on mobile device (tested on iOS 8 Safari and Chrome).
It works perfectly on desktop

I have used the Safari dev kit to remove and test the different parts of the code and ended up with only head tags and body tags with only simple text, and my website was still not scrolling. So my guess is that it is something that occurs on page load.

My website can be seen [here](http://runkin.winmychallenge.com/).

Answer (score 8):

Add Following lines to your css :

```
overflow: scroll;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

Comment: Added in the body {} but doesn't seem to work either!

Answer (score 0):

A temporary fix would be to style your body tag with height:100%.

```
body {
    height:100%;
}
```

Once you have content in your website, it should be fine.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work !

Comment: Do a html validation first - There are quite a few errors in your website. http://validator.w3.org/