# Website often refuses to scroll on iPhone (Safari)

Tags: javascript, html, css, iphone

For some reason, my website often refuses to scroll, but only on iPhones.

Devices/browsers that **do** work:

- iPad (Safari)
- Android phones (Chrome)
- PC (Chrome (including DevTools emulation) & IE11)

Devices that show the bug:

- iPhone 4S
- iPhone 5
- iPhone 6

So clearly it is iPhone related.. It's like there's a timeout on scrolling only on iPhone. I'll try to describe the bug as good as possible.

After I load the site, I have to wait like 5 seconds before I can scroll. Then I scroll down a bit. During the scrolling, the scrollbar can be seen (as normal). When the scrollbar has faded, scrolling the **opposite** direction is blocked for like 5 seconds. When I scroll and scroll the opposite direction *before* the scrollbar fades, it scrolls as expected.

Also when I want to change scrolling direction, it's like I have to swipe twice to "initialize" scrolling. I have to **scroll**, **wait**, **scroll** to actually scroll that direction.

So:

- Scroll down (**scrolls**), wait, scroll down (**scrolls**) - *same direction scrolls*
- Scroll up (**scrolls**), wait, scroll up (**scrolls**) - *same direction scrolls*
- Scroll down (**scrolls**), scroll up (**scrolls**) - *changing direction before scrollbar fades*
- Scroll down (**scrolls**), wait, scroll up (**nothing**) - *changing direction*
- Scroll down (**scrolls**), wait, scroll up (**nothing**), wait, scroll up (**scrolls**) - *changing direction, have to scroll and wait twice*

At `wait`, I wait like 3 seconds. If I don't wait long enough when scrolling the opposite direction, it just doesn't scroll.

The website uses MeteorJS and jQuery. I've tried some mobile-utility scripts, like [iScroll](http://iscrolljs.com/) and [FastClick](http://ftlabs.github.io/fastclick/), but they don't seem to help.

Comment: In Google Chrome, there is the Dev tool to show the website on different mobile devices. Does it happen there?

Comment: @Alexey - no it doesn't

Comment: Are there any script errors when you check in the Dev tools and use iPhone?

Comment: @Alexey - I presume you mean DevTools in Chrome and not on the iPhone itself, then no (don't think that iPhone itself has DevTools)

Comment: I think then the best solution would be to look around MeteorJS for some delays. Don't know your structure, maybe turn it off and just see if no JS solution still forces your app to do weird scroll.

Comment: @Alexey - I can't really turn off MeteorJS, as it is the fullstack JavaScript application. Turning it off also disables other devices from scrolling :P

Comment: I could only guess it is due to some loading issues which causes everything to slow down.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok so I started commenting stuff out for hours, just to find out that the thing that was blocking the scrolling was the menu.

I have a menu, hidden in the background with the following styles:

```
menu {
  opacity: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

I really thought that having a `z-index` of -1 made it non-interactable when stuff with a higher z-index is in front of it, but apparently it doesn't on iPhone (on Android it does..).

Changing `overflow-y: scroll;` to `hidden` when the menu isn't open (and `scroll` when the menu is open) fixes it. Also a good idea is to just hide the menu altogether.

Comment: Was it the overflow-y that was causing the scrolling not to work?

Comment: Yes partly. The problem was 2 elements on top of each other that both scrolled. The menu and the body in my case. I've "hidden" the menu with `opacity: 0`, but it still responded to scrolling.. I should've  used `display: none` or `pointer-events: none`

Comment: ah ok i got you. My problem was needing to use -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; so that ios would work.

Comment: You could also consider putting the div manually outside the window with a left:-200%; or something of that nature (although ik that's not super clean and this project is 2 years old :))

Comment: That's a good solution, though the requirements stated that it was a fade in menu, so no side slide in ;)

Answer (score 7):

**EDIT:** I've spoke to Apple about this bug. They acknowledged its existence but decided not to prioritize it for now. If this bug is hurting you, please comment on https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=169509.

What the bug is:

The problem for me occurs only when you reach the beginning/end of the scrolling layer and then the beginning of your next gesture goes in the same direction. Then the webkit wheel event decides that it can't go that way and doesn't let you scroll at all.

There is a workaround for this: never let your scrolling layer reach the beginning or end of the scroll!

```
div.addEventListener('scroll',() =>
    div.scrollTop = Math.max(1, Math.min(div.scrollTop,
                                         div.scrollHeight - div.clientHeight - 1));
);
```

I hope some people still involved in webkit can fix this (I'm a bit retired from browser code), it's hurting scrollable layers on ios everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with the menu scroll, often it refused to scroll after menu container changed its size (problem causes only in iPhone). I found the solution in my case, just toggling the css overflow styles. Like I had on container these styles

```
.container {    
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 280px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

After every opening the menu just run this script

```
$('.container').css('overflow-y', 'hidden');
setTimeout(function () {
  $('.container').css('overflow-y', 'scroll');
}, 50);
```

Comment: The setTimeout miliseconds may not be correct, in my case it worked from 500.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar issue for iOS.

After a lot of hair was pulled out, I found a solution that worked for me:
[response by Wes R](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-v1/issues/155#issuecomment-411110252)

The idea is that you listen for a touchstart event, capture the touch's Y position, listen for the touchmove, capture that touch's Y position, to work out the touch direction. If at the top already, and the direction is 'up' then `event.preventDefault()` to stop the browser attempting to scroll up, do same for scrolling down at the bottom of the page.

It was for a similar issue with same direction scrolling while at scroll boundary, sorry if it's irrelevant for your use case, I might've misunderstood OP :P

Answer (score 0):

Solved adding

> **-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;**

to container class as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28850312/2903561)

Comment: Doesn't seem to work.