# Website is not scrolling in iphone 5 and iphone 6

Tags: html, iphone, wordpress

The page is not scrolling after the view port section. I didn't use any overflow hidden property in code. Please help on this.

Comment: Please Share us some code, so that we can check!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29531718/website-often-refuses-to-scroll-on-iphone-safari 

Check this SO post!

Comment: No. Its not working