# Locking the body scroll, blocks target element scrolling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll

I am using the following library for locking scrolling of the body of page and only allow scrolling on my modal if it is open.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-scroll-lock

My modal `AddItemModal` is a portal so inside `index.html` file I have this.

```
<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <div id="add-item-modal"></div>
</body>
```

NavigationIcons component (where modal is opened)

```
const NavigationIcons = (props) => {
  let targetElement = document.getElementById("add-item-modal");

  useEffect(() => {
    ...
    return () => clearAllBodyScrollLocks();
  }, []);

  const renderAddItemModal = () => {
    if (props.addItem) {
      disableBodyScroll(targetElement);
      return <AddItemModal />;
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="main-4" onClick={() => props.openAddItemModal()}>
      {renderAddItemModal()}
    </div>
  );
}
```

AddItemModalHeader component (where modal is closed)

```
const AddItemModalHeader = (props) => {
  let targetElement = document.getElementById("add-item-modal");

  return (
    <div className="modal-header">
      add item
      <div className="close" onClick={(e) => {
        props.handleModalClose(e);
        enableBodyScroll(targetElement);
      }}>
       close
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

In documentation it is written that `targetElement` must be the the modal that I want to display. But since the application is rendered inside `root` div and modal displayed in `add-item-modal`, shouldn't it be the `root` instead and apply to it the provided functions such as `enableBodyScroll`, `disableBodyScroll`, `clearAllBodyScrollLocks`. I did try with both `root` and `add-item-modal` and in both cases the scrolling does not work on the modal when I test from my iOS device.

The example provided there does not make this clear to me. Could someone explain what am I doing wrong here?

**UPDATE**

Others that might have this issue on iOS devices please see the following well-explained answer from Github thread
https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-v1/issues/155#issuecomment-411110252

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some know issues with [`body-scroll-lock`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-scroll-lock) are

- Doesn't work on Android webview
- Doesn't work on PC with mouse wheel
- Doesn't work on iOS, if you touch somewhere instead of targetElement
- Must pass targetElement, even if it's not necessary

Enter [`tua-body-scroll-lock`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tua-body-scroll-lock)

---

> Please know I don't have any connection with `tua-body-scroll-lock`.

---

`tua-body-scroll-lock` has the same functions that `body-scroll-lock` provides. Like

- `disableBodyScroll` alias for `lock`
- `enableBodyScroll` alias for `unlock`
- `clearAllBodyScrollLocks` alias for `clearBodyLocks`

I made a fiddle with an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/oeht43cL/) using `tua-body-scroll-lock`

Your code should then be like

```
import {lock, unlock, clearBodyLocks} from 'tua-body-scroll-lock';

const NavigationIcons = (props) => {
  ...
  useEffect(() => {
    ...
    return () => clearBodyLocks();
  }, []);

  const renderAddItemModal = () => {
    if (props.addItem) {
      lock(targetElement);
      return <AddItemModal />;
    }
  };

  ...
}

const AddItemModalHeader = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="modal-header">
      add item
      <div className="close" onClick={(e) => {
        props.handleModalClose(e);
        unlock(targetElement);
      }}>
       close
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: I am looking at your example and wonder where did you take ```clearBodyLocks``` variable from. I think my problem is that I am not targeting the right node element and I want to understand better what have you done to understand how to make it work.

Comment: The `clearBodyLocks` function has the same use as your `clearAllBodyScrollLocks`, I imported it at the top of the code along with the `lock` and `unlock` functions

Comment: Excuse my mistake, I meant ```bodyScrollLock``` from example

Comment: Oooh. I imported the `tua-body-scroll-lock` with a `script` tag in the HTML. So the `bodyScrollLock` is like the object that holds the `lock`, `unlock` and `clearBodyLocks` functions

Comment: I edited the `jsFiddle` to log out the `bodyScrollLock` check out the new link from my edited answer

Comment: This allows to have scrollable content but on iOS if I play a bit with scrolling the modal (going to the very top), at one moment it freezes and scrolls the body element (not the modal one), what I have done was to give an ```id``` to ```body``` tag from ```index.html``` to lock this, but this issue still persists.

Comment: Do you reach the top of the modal before you start experiencing the problem?... if yes, I think that is a default behavior of iOS where by if you keep on scrolling upwards and there’s nowhere else to scroll to, the body is dragged down

Comment: Yes scoll upwards or downwards when there is no place to scroll to, I have looked and tried tricks such as body overflow: hidden, position: fixed, but still body is scrollable

Comment: Well it's a bug that has been acknowledged by apple... Check the answers to this question for potential fixes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29531718/website-often-refuses-to-scroll-on-iphone-safari

Comment: If you want me to write out the potential answer let me know

Comment: could you please tell me what do you see as a potential answer to this? I have tried on my iOS device their example from here https://tuateam.github.io/tua-body-scroll-lock/ and it works on my phone, it seems to me that I do it as I should with```lock(targetElement)``` and disable any scrolling from body but it freezes when I go to very bottom and scroll further on my example but on their it works just fine. I do not know and understand where the issue might be.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231044/discussion-between-a-mola-and-user12051965).

Answer (score 2):

If you look at their source code, the only thing that [disableBodyScroll](https://github.com/willmcpo/body-scroll-lock/blob/b6292818ef111a145ff1c7ee5954a387d4ebed7f/src/bodyScrollLock.js#L155) does internally is attaching `ontouchstart` and `ontouchmove` events if the device is **IOS** and just preventing the event (by calling `e.preventDefault()`) conditionally if the targetElement is near to the scrollable boundaries.

So if I understood it correctly, the `targetElement` must be a scrollable element otherwise it'll never bypass those boundary check and it'll block the scroll.

In your case, I think `add-item-modal` is not a scrollable element thus it's not working. Try with any scrollable element with in the modal as `targetElement`.